# Add custom form in magento admin side

Tags: forms, magento, admin, magento-1.7

I want to make custom form in magento with two section like (two green box)

[image: There is 2 green part I want to make in admin]

Also I wand to make three fields instead of one like

[image: one label and three fields like DD-MM-YYYY]

I have make code like

```
protected function _prepareForm() {
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
        $this->setForm($form);
        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('slider_form', array('legend' => Mage::helper('slider')->__('Slider information')));

        $fieldset->addField('link_title', 'text', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('slider')->__('Link Title'),
            'class' => 'required-entry',
            'required' => true,
            'name' => 'link_title',
        ));
        $fieldset->addField('link', 'text', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('slider')->__('Link'),
            'class' => 'required-entry',
            'required' => true,
            'name' => 'link',
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('content', 'text', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('slider')->__('Text'),
            'class' => 'required-entry',
            'required' => true,
            'name' => 'content',
        ));

       ....
       ....
}
```

Can anybody help!!!